# How to return a JavaScript 'native' array from a C# method?

Tags: c#, javascript, interop, com-interop

I'm trying to call a C# method from JavaScript by using `ActiveXObject`:

```
var myobj = new ActiveXObject('myobject');
var arr = myobj.GetArray();
```

Eventually, `arr` will contain a `SAFEARRAY` object, but not `JScript` array. Is there any way to return native JavaScript object from a C# method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution by myself, but no documentation exists for this part.
The solution is to use `JScript.ArrayObject` in the following way:

```
ArrayObject _lastField;
byte[] byteArray = new byte[]{2,1,2,3};
object[] array = new object[byteArray.Length];
byteArray.CopyTo(array, 0);
_lastField = Microsoft.JScript.GlobalObject.Array.ConstructArray(array);
```

After that you will be able to use the `_lastField` array in JavaScript like a native array:

```
var myobj = new ActiveXObject('myobject');
var arr = myobj.LastField;
alert(arr[1]);
```

Comment: I would be extremely wary of this. It's quite likely MS are going to hand you xbrowser issues given the "JScript" and the ActiveX. The JSON approach is going to be more flexible and more reliable imho.

Answer (score 8):

You can return a [JSON](http://www.json.org/) string and then parse into a JavaScript object. There are a number of .NET libraries available to serialize .NET objects into JSON and vice-versa-

- [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx)
- [Microsoft ASP.NET AJAX library](http://www.asp.net/ajax/)
- [JSONSharp](http://code.google.com/p/jsonsharp/)

to name a few.

This [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596593/when-creating-a-javascriptconverter-how-to-return-an-array) may be of use to you

Comment: No, this is not the case. I know that similar possible and actually was done by my colleague by using C++, but I'm not familiar with that, so I wish to know how can I do it by using C#.

Answer (score 1):

You may [return delimited Joined String](http://www.asptricks.net/2016/05/return-array-string-in-activex-c-solved.html) in C# and can split into JavaScript

```
//C#
public string getArryString()
{
string[] arrstring = new string[]{"1","2","3"};
return string.Join(",", arrstring);
}

//Javascript
var arrstring = objActiveX.getArryString().split(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

Via VBArray it can work like this:

1. Return object[] from C# (declare so in the dispinterface).
2. To get a native JS array in JScript use VBArray:

   ```
   var jsArray = new VBArray(myobj.GetArray()).toArray();
   for (i = 0; i < jsArray.length; i++) 
   {
      // use jsArray[i]
   }
   ```

Background information:

- JScript supports SafeArrays of Variants only 
  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaiprakash/archive/2007/01/09/jscript-supports-safearrays-of-variants-only.aspx
- Eric's Complete Guide To Type Signatures Of Scriptable Object Models
  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2004/07/14/183241.aspx