# Javascript and C# COM interaction

Tags: javascript, interop, activex

I am using C# COM Interop techniques to interact with some device from website using ActiveX. Right now I can call C# codes from javascript and pass only string values. But I intend to pass javascript structure into C# method and the reverse. How can I do that.

Right now as an alternative I pass JSON formatted string from C# code and generate javascript object runtime using eval. But I want more control on that.

Thanks
Maksud

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/647696/how-to-return-a-javascript-native-array-from-a-c-method

Comment: Thanks, but it also uses the JSON thing. I want to use something native. I have the drivers activex object and I have seen the uses. But can't find any sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using NewtonSoft's JSON Library as I could not find native solution.